# how to add multiple domains into DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS as an environment variable

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

in django 4.1 application I'm trying to add several allowed hosts in my .env file as an environment variable like this -> `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST=synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0`
but only first domain working correctly and after `echo $DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST` shows only synapse-developmentcenter.am and here is my settings.py line addressing .env file ->

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
if not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS += os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST').split(' ')
```

running `cat .env` showing correctly and when trying to export it again only first domain getting there for the rest it shows -> `bash: export:` 127.0.0.1': not a valid identifier`

I tried change variable types to this -> `[DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST=synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0]` or
`["DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST=synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0"]` even like this -> `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOST="synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0"` but neither of them worked

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable as follows (two examples).

Windows, Powershell:

```
$Env:DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS = "synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0"
```

Ubuntu:

```
export DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS="synapse-developmentcenter.am www.synapse-developmentcenter.am 127.0.0.1 localhost 0.0.0.0"
```

Both ways will end up with the same list:

```
import os
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")
>> ['synapse-developmentcenter.am', 'www.synapse-developmentcenter.am', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '0.0.0.0']
```